# c# MVVM Listbox Remember Selected Item after TabChange

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, listbox

i have searched for days but not found any solution for the following Problem:
My parent is an TabControl.

In one tab i have an viewmodel with an listbox or listview with a lot of items.
when i select some item at the end of the list and then select an other tab an back to the list the item is select but i can not see it, because its outside the visible area.

What ca i do to fix the visible area ? So when i came back to my list the visible area of the listbox is the same as i leave.

sorry for the bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual tree (XAML) for a tab item is cleared when the selected tab changes, this is by design, this means things like the selected item in a ListBox\ListView are not remember by the View.

You have a couple of options:

Implement a tab control which remembers the visual state\tree for each tab - there are a lot of blog posts about how to do this,

or

You can remember the selected item in the ViewModel and when this is rebound when you go back to the tab it should scroll the selected item back into view. To do this you will have to bind the SelectedItem\SelectedItems properties depending on the selection mode you have chosen for the control.

Comment: I found this, a short overview and i think it's what i search. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212233/Persist-the-Visual-Tree-when-switching-tabs-in-the)